# Color table column on input focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with an `<input>` in each `<td>`, I want all of the column `<td>`s to get the class `.highlighted` when you are focused on a `<input>`. And to remove the class from all the other columns and `<td>`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/amitkeren/c6gbp5kh/

Comment: Please, add the relevant code inside a question (keeping the fiddle link to the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

```
fiddle not working so i'll just type it here.
```

but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5c773ojk/) you go